# PHPUnitのモック機能を使いテストを行いたいのですが、うまく置き換わってくれません。

Tags: php, fuelphp, phpunit, テスト

FuelPHPを使用しています。
↓のようなコードのテストをPHPUnitで行いたいと考えています。

```
class Item_Relation extends \Utility\base {
    public function get_item_info($account, $item_name) {
        $item_master_instance = new \Utility\Item_Master();
        $item_master_id = $item_master_instance->get_id($account, $item_name);
        return $item_master_id;
    }
}
```

get_idメソッドと_get_item_infoメソッドのテストをモックでやろうとしているのですが、
↓のコードを書くとモックで既存のメソッドを置き換えてくれません。

```
class Test_Item_Relation extends TestCase
{
    private $item_relation_instance = null;
    public function setUp() {
        $this->item_relation_instance = new \Utility\Item_Relation();
    }
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function get_item_info() {
        $item_master_mock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Utility\Item_Master::class)
            ->setMethods(['get_id'])
            ->getMock();
        $item_master_mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('get_id')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1));

        $item_master_id = $this->item_relation_instance->get_item_info('unit_test_account', 'item_name');

        $this->assertSame(1, $item_master_id);
    }
}
```

PHPUnitのマニュアルを見て↑を書いたのですが、想定通り動かないので、
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しましたので、解決策を書きます。
調べていくといろいろ勘違いしていた部分が分かったのですが、
私のやりたかったことはJava(djUnit)でいう
バーチャルモックをPHPUnitでどうやって実装するかということでした。

いくつかのテックブログで
依存関係があるメソッドを置き換えてくれるライブラリは
PHPUnitには存在しないと書かれていたので
AspectMockを導入することで解決しました。
https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Comment: get_item_infoの内部でItem_Masterを自分で作るのでなく、外部から注入する形ならMockBuilderが使えたんでしょうね…。

Comment: おっしゃる通りItem_Masterを外部から注入すればMockBuilderが使えるようです。仮にItem_Masterを外部から注入する場合でもコントローラー側でItem_Relationのインスタンスを作成することになると思います。この場合、コントローラーのテストをどういう風に書くのが良いのかまたはどういう設計が良いか教えてもらうことは可能でしょうか。

Comment: 私もきれいな答えを持ち合わせていないのと、本質問とは少し別の話題ですから、別途質問していただくと答えが得られる…かもしれません。こういう言い方しかできず申し訳ないですが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた通り別途質問を立てさせていただきました。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30491